# How to call Java via SAP JCO 3 from an ABAP

Tags: java, abap, sapjco3

This is for a Windows system. From the research I have found I know you need to register a program with the `SAP Gateway`. The program is an `RFC server` program. Need to use `SM59` to setup the destination, choose Register Server Program and put the name of the program under Start on Application Server. I have seen an example `RFC Server` program from `SAP`. I have seen the use of this command to register the program in the

```
OS (Unix): rfcexec -g -a -x
```

I know you can view if it is running using `SMGW`. What I don't know is if the RFC Server program is the Java program you want to execute or just a listener that then is used to kick off your Java program. Also, I think I have to get the rfcexec program from the `NW RFC SDK` files? I would have thought the `JCO library` should have everything you need to call SAP and call Java. I have been able to use the example Java program to call an SAP RFC but I want to go from `ABAP` to Java now. What am I missing?

Comment: As it is stated right now, the question is way too broad to be answered in the short Q&A format of stack overflow. Can you narrow your problem down and thus improve your question?

Comment: I changed it and tried to eliminate what I know to narrow it down to what I need to know. Difficult when you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In zip file there is an example for client in file "StepByStepClient.java". Did you try it?